# Show more/less button in Drupal view columns

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

My view looks as below:

[image]

In this view the "Category" column is a list of taxonomy terms selected against every file field. I would like to show only 2 terms and then show a "show more/show less" button to show and hide the remaining terms. So I would like to see something like below:

[image]

I tried setting "Trim" functionality and the view doesn't allow that on reference term column. I also tried the combination of "Multiple field settings" and "re-write results" by setting certain number of fields with Trim functionality. but that trims individual taxonomy term.

Any help on how this can be achieved????

Comment: There is no inbuilt functionality for this in views as far as I am aware. It could easily be done with a bit of javascript though.

Comment: Can you guide on where to start? I added a DIV wrapper with a class name around the column and now trying to add show more/less button through javascript. Do I need to do this through Twig template?